# error 403 : jquery bootstrap and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to code igniter and I'm setting up this includes folder inside view. and the css isn't working.

Here is the error

```
GET http://localhost/hr/%22public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css%22 
index:9 

GET http://localhost/hr/%22public/css/style.css%22 
index:12 

GET http://localhost/hr/%22public/js/booststrap.js%22 
index:11 

GET http://localhost/hr/%22public/js/jquery.js%22 403 (Forbidden)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the error and how can I resolve this.

header.php

```
<!--DOCTYPE html-->

<html lang="en">

<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=<?php echo base_url();?>"public/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href=<?php echo base_url();?>"public/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

        <script src=<?php echo base_url()?>"public/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src=<?php echo base_url()?>"public/js/booststrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
Header
</header>
```

I used these two tutorials to set this up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5nTCqmxmzI -(but the version of the jquery we downloaded are different versions)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fLtTRYQX0M - and this one.

Comment: which server your using and which user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear you have invalid links for all of them.  You have your starting double quote AFTER the base URL.  Move `<?php echo base_url();?>` after the starting double quote rather than before it.

All your requests are currently doing:

`http://localhost/hr/"public/css/style.css"` when in reality I'm assuming the actual valid URLS are `http://localhost/hr/public/css/style.css`.

Comment: http://localhost/hr/public/js/booststrap.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) here comes the next error.

Comment: Can you provide the directory structure of your files?  Can you also copy one of the full paths of one of those CSS or JS files here so we can look?

Comment: Last but not least, try removing the "public" from the path and see if that works. So do `localhost/hr/js/bootstrap.js`, etc.

Comment: the location of my css, js, and images folder are inside hr/public

one of the full paths of the js are localhost/hr/public/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: Did you try removing `public` from the path? A lot of things designate a folder like `public` to be the location of static assets (CSS, JS, etc.), but the URL doesn't actually include the public part, it's simply the directory where the files are house.  For example, `localhost/hr/public/js/bootstrap.js` is the directory, but to access it via a URL it's actually `localhost/hr/js/bootstrap.js`.